# Make default.asp and default.aspx load when given url

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

We are using IIS6 on server 2003.
We have several web sites that use classic ASP.
Now we have 1 web site that uses ASP.NET.
This asp.net website is on the same server as the classic asp websites.

Until recently, our users have their bookmarks
( we have many users that have a bookmark) as

http://www.myasp.com/weather
and 
http://www.myasp.com/weather/default.asp  would load up.

After creating this ASP.NET ("http://www.myNet.com/weatherNet")
 web site on the server 2003 with IIS6,

## a user   goes to (classic asp)   http://www.myasp.com/weather they get error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
```

When a user types in or bookmark "http://www.myasp.com/weather",
How can I make classic asp 
"http://www.myasp.com/weather/default.asp" load?

Also how can I make "http://www.myNet.com/weatherNet"
load up (ASP.NET) "http://www.myNet.com/weatherNet/default.aspx"?

I checked IIS and ASP is already Allowed and
ASP.Net v4.0.30319 is Allowed.

Comment: Are they in separate application pools? Are they configured as separate web applications? If yes, you can tell both what their respective "default" should be in the documents tab.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the default.asp(x) page on IIS for that website/virtual directory.

Follow the [guide here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx)

The details being:

> **To set up or change the default document**
>
> 1. In IIS Manager, double-click the local computer, right-click the Web Sites folder or an individual Web site folder, and then click
>      Properties.
> 2. Click the Documents tab.
> 3. Select the Enable default content page check box.
> 4. Click Add to add a new default document to the list.
> 5. Click the document you want to remove from the list and click Remove.
> 6. Click a document from the list and click Move Up or Move down to change the order in which default documents are served to client
>      requests.
> 7. Click OK.

So add your default.asp(x) page as the default document and you'll be fine.

Comment: I already have that Documents->default.asp in IIS. This was working until I installed the ASP.NET website. Now none of the classic asp web sites will automatically load the "default.asp".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your "default.aspx" page is getting preference over "default.asp" page. In IIS's default document tab, remove all the document names and just add "default.asp". Restart IIS and try.

These settings can be done at folder / application level in IIS too. Its just you'll need to repeat the process for each folder to either set "default.asp" or "default.aspx" as your default document.